# How much should you spoil when advertising a book?

Tags: creative-writing

I'm trying to promote one of my new books and so far I'm not having much luck. I'm pretty sure it's just the way I'm wording things, so I'm wondering if I should spoil a little to get the readers more interested? Should I just flat out tell people what the love interest is? Or just allude to her not being human?

Comment: It would help if you told us what your book actually *is*. We can't really tell you how to market a book whose plot you've only vaguely alluded to.

Comment: "One of" your books?  How did the others go?  Why is this one different?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you go to your bookshelf (kindle, etc) and check out your 10-20-30 favorite books.

You know the story of these books. How does the back cover text relate to it?

How does the back cover hook you as a reader?

Another thing to consider is to be honest on the back cover with regards to genre, type of story, and other general facts about the book. E.g. Koontz's books seem to mostly be "boy meets girl and together they fight evil"—you can usually tell already on the back cover.

You're not going to win anything by trying to make a romance reader buy a sci-fi novel or a crime fan pick up a fantasy novel.

Make it easy for the right reader to pick up your novel or the wrong reader might have given you their money but could also cut you down in their review or rating, or on Twitter, etc.

Another thing never to do is when you read the back cover, then read the book, and gain nothing new... ok, a little characterization and a little worldbuilding, but the end alluded to in the back cover, that's how it all ended. I could have saved myself the money and just read the back cover on that one. But I think this one is very obviously wrong, and I've only seen it once in some trash produced by the spouse of a favorite author...